# IndexError: too many indices for array for basic program

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This program is very simple, but I do not know why I get this error:

> IndexError: too many indices for array

The error is caught for `df1` (doesn't even go to `df2`). Can someone explain why I get this error? I think the bigger question is what's the logic for having a 2 by 1 subplot that I am not understanding.

Here is the program:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(5)
y = range(0,10,2)

w = x
z = y

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1':x,'col2':y})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1':w,'col2':z})

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
df1.plot(ax=axes[0,0])
df2.plot(ax=axes[1,0])
```

Comment: Use `fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, squeeze=False)` as shown in the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the correct indices. Since you are using `plt.subplots(2,1)`, the `axes` object has length of 2 where the first and the second subplots are accessed using indices `[0]` and `[1]` respectively. If you do `print (axes.shape)`, you will get `(2,)` so you have no second index. For `plt.subplots(2,2)`, the `print (axes.shape)` would give `(2,2)` where you can use the double indices.

You can use `axes[0, 0]`, `axes[1, 0]`, `axes[0, 1]`, `axes[1, 1]` and so on when you have more than 1 column. For a single column, `axes[0, 0]` has to be replaced by `ax[0]` and `axes[1, 0]` has to be replaced by `ax[1]`.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
print (len(axes))
# 2

df1.plot(ax = axes[0])
df2.plot(ax = axes[1])
```

**Alternative** approach would be

```
axes[0].plot(df1)
axes[1].plot(df2)
```

[image]

**Your way works for a 2 by 2 subplots**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
print (axes.shape)
# (2, 2)

df1.plot(ax = axes[0,0])
df2.plot(ax = axes[0,1])
df1.plot(ax = axes[1,0])
df2.plot(ax = axes[1,1])
```

[image]